# Unable to browse a page hosted in Visual Studio dev server using firefox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, firefox

I am developing a web app using ASP.net 4.0.

When I browse it using IE8, it appears all correct.

But When I try to browse it using FireFox 19.0, it says:

```
 Connection refused
 Description: Connection refused.
```

It gives a 502 error, and gives a similar error in chrome too.

Answer (score 0):

When using the VS embedded server, keep in mind that it only accepts connection typed as `http://localhost:<port>/` from the machine where it is running from.

Maybe double check that you are not using the machine name or anything different than localhost in firefox or chrome.